# AWS Cloudformation deploy introduce new variable

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'm deploying an cloudformation template using

`aws cloudformation deploy` and the `--parameter-overrides  ParameterKey=prm1,ParameterValue=val1 ParameterKey=prm15,ParameterValue=val15` flag.  `prm15` is being introduced new to the stack and my cloudformation template has the following

```
  prm15:
    Description: Desc
    Type: String
```

However when I try to deploy this it fails saying the parameter `prm15` should have a value.  Bearing in mind this is being introduced new I kind of understand the error since that parameter does not exist on the existing stack.  How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The `--parameter-overrides` should be:

```
--parameter-overrides prm1=val1 prm15=val15
```